# jQuery: Dynamically generated "Remove" button not working properly

Tags: jquery

I have a `form` with a `button` that is able to dynamically add a `div` that contains a `paragraph` and a "remove" `button`:

```
<!--form-->
<form></form>

<!--dynamically add div with paragraph and remove button-->
<button onclick="addParagraph()">Add Paragraph</button>

<script>

    //remove div
    $(".remove").click(function() {
        $(this).parent.remove();
    });

    //add paragraph div
    function addParagraph(){
                $("form").append('<div><textarea></textarea><button class="remove">Remove</button></div>');
    }

</script>
```

Unfortunately, if I add more than one div and click a remove button, it removes all of the dynamically generated divs. How can I get it so it just removes the one div?

I have also tried `$(this).closest("div").remove();`, but same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform **[`event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** for dynamically added elements.

```
$(document).on('click',".remove",function() {
     $(this).parent.remove();
});
```

Working Snippet below:

```js
//remove div
$(document).on('click', ".remove", function(e) {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});

//add paragraph div
function addParagraph() {
  $("form").append('<div><textarea></textarea><button class="remove">Remove</button></div>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form></form>
<button onclick="addParagraph()">Add Paragraph</button>
```

Comment: you are missing a dot after document

Comment: Yep.. @NidhinChandran Thanks for the info.. Updated the answer..

Comment: Bingo. Will accept this answer when it lets me. Thanks.

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 1):

For dynamically created element you have to use `.live()` However, `live()` was deprecated in 1.7 in favour of `on()`, and completely removed in `1.9`. The `live()` signature:

If you have greater version of jQuery than 1.9 you can use jQuery.fn.on

I would recommend to use `.on` below is a signature of `.on` function

```
$(document).on( eventName, selector, function(){} );

$("body").on("click", ".remove", function(event){
    //Do Some stuff
});
```

Solved version:

```
$("body").on('click', '.remove', function(event)
{
     $(this).parent.remove();
});
```